# unable to access MySQL server remotely on centOS

Tags: mysql, centos, remote-access

I have centos 6.5 on which MySQL 5.6.21 is running, i am trying to access this MySQL server from my Linux 14.0.4 LTS server but every time it show ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.192.4.86' (113).

I am able to access centOS using putty and winscp from my windows machine but not able to connect centOS mysql server from any other operating system.

I did following things.

skip-networking is also commented.
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.192.4.222' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';

Add following things in iptables

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.192.4.222 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.192.4.85 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

port 3306 is also in listing mode i already checked.

```
netstat -nat |grep 3306

tcp  0  0 :::3306  :::*  LISTEN
```

but not able to access centos MySQL Server remotely.

If any one know where I am wrong or something missing please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` instead of `skip-networking`. Also make sure you used `flush privileges` after the grants in MySQL.

Comment: i already did this and it's not worked.

Comment: Hi, any one have any idea where I am wrong plz help me....

Comment: And you granted access to all IP addresses you need to connect from (in your question there is only `192.192.4.222`)? Also try to disable firewall completely and grant access to all IP's (`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%'`). Of course after you identified your problem you should make it secure again...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know what is going on with CentOS, It show me 3306 port is Listing mode but it did not accept request that comes from different host. So disable the firewall using service iptables stop command and after that reboot the centOS server and after that i am able to access it from any Virtual machine. This is miracle for me, i know my ans is stupid but it is work for me. After 2days hardwork i got something and that helped me.

Comment: I advice to all if any one have same problem then first disable the firewall so you get exact idea about whether problem in MySQL or Network.

Answer (score 1):

login to your mysql with root username and root password

`mysql -u root -proot`

Run Below commands to run mysql as remote host

`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO mysqluser@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysqluser';`

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

`CREATE USER 'mysqluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysqluser';`

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Now Check you are able to login to hostname with username and password

`mysql -h yourhostname -u mysqluser -pmysqluser`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out.

**Configuration:**
By default MySQL will listen for connections only from the local host. To enable remote connections like the one used by mysqlworkbench you will need to modify your **/etc/my.cnf** and change

```
bind-address 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address 0.0.0.0
```

or simply comment out the line completely. Once this is done, restart MySQL with the command.

```
service mysql restart
```

**MySQL Privilege:**
Or, like the ones mentioned on initial answers, you could grant privilege under MySQL itself. Like so,

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'your-public-ip' identified by 'your-password'
```